# Swing JButton is glitching with JCheckBox focus state

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcheckbox

I have a JPanel set with the Windows Look and Feel. I have 3 JCheckBoxes, including 2 disabled ones which don't interfere with this problem. However, the non-disabled one is glitching with the JButton I have later in this JPanel:

The JCheckBox code:

```
JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("TTxJIRA Bash");
checkBox.setSize(300, (checkBox.getFontMetrics(checkBox.getFont()).getHeight()));
checkBox.setLocation(10, 100);
checkBox.setVisible(true);
checkBox.setSelected(true);
checkBox.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
checkBox.setFocusable(false);
add(checkBox);
```

And the JButton code:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Install");
button.setSize(80, 25);
button.setLocation(getWidth() - 100, getHeight() - 60);
button.setFocusable(false);
button.setVisible(true);
add(button);
```

When I hover on the button, then hover on the checkbox, this glitch occurs:

[image]

My wild guess makes me think this has to do with two components being focused at the same time, but adding the `button.setFocusable(false);` did not help.

Comment: That's not glitching. That's what happens when you use absolute positioning. Use layout managers and your problems will be solved.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman No, the getWidth() and getHeight() method are the width and height of the JPanel.

Comment: @Momo, When asking a question post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. We can't tell the context of how the above code is used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little runnable example that shows you how you could use `LayoutManagers` for that, because LayoutManagers will fix your problems you had with absolute positioning. (Please note that this is probably not the best solution and that the LineBorders are just for visualization)

Kinda messy code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class LayoutManagerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("Install");

        JCheckBox cb1 = new JCheckBox("1");
        cb1.setEnabled(false);

        JCheckBox cb2 = new JCheckBox("2");
        cb2.setEnabled(false);

        JCheckBox cb3 = new JCheckBox("3");

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        southPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        JPanel westPanel = new JPanel();
        westPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,1));
        westPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        JPanel southEastPanel = new JPanel();
        southEastPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        mainPanel.add(southPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainPanel.add(westPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
        southPanel.add(southEastPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
        westPanel.add(cb1);
        westPanel.add(cb2);
        westPanel.add(cb3);
        southEastPanel.add(button, gbc);
        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```